# How to find files by type and show it's respective path

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, zsh

I'm trying to list all **JPG files** inside a directory tree to create a report of JPG files inside this tree without search inside every directory one by one.

The command I'm using is this one:

```
ls -lhAR | grep jpg
```

The command didn't work as I spected because it just showed me the list of JPG files but didn't show me their path.

There's any way to acomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Do you just need the paths, or do you need the other information given by `less -l` as well?

Comment: I just need the paths, and the answer @John1024 gave did a really good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec ls -lhA {} +
```

Comment: It worked beautifully

Answer (score 1):

Using recursive globbing (`**`) this command should do the trick:

```
ls -lhA **/*.jpg
```

This works by default in *zsh*; when you use *bash* (version 4 or above) you need to enable those advanced globbing patterns via

```
shopt -s globstar
```